# How to solve for the eigenvalue in matrix?

Tags: matrix

For which value of $a$ in the matrix `{{a,2}, {3,4}}` has the matrix eigenvalue of $0$? 
How to solve it in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Do you need to do this by hand or using Mathematica?

Comment: I have to use mathematica.

Comment: Then look up the function `Eigenvalues` in the documentation

Comment: I found it how to find, but not how to find for the value a. :(

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: People have voted your question down very probably because you didn't show due diligence. It looks like you didn't bother to search on the documentation (or showed us that you did). You didn't even bother to write the matrix in the proper syntax. Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are likely to get great answers.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 6):

To get the expresions for the [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html)

```
Eigenvalues[{{a, 2} , {3, 4}}]
```

> ```
> {1/2 (4 + a - Sqrt[40 - 8 a + a^2]),  1/2 (4 + a + Sqrt[40 - 8 a + a^2])}
> ```

make each expresion [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) to zero  (`f@x` is the [`Prefix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html) form of `f[x]`)

```
 Thread@Equal[Eigenvalues[{{a, 2} , {3, 4}}], 0]
```

> ```
> {1/2 (4 + a - Sqrt[40 - 8 a + a^2]) == 0, 1/2 (4 + a + Sqrt[40 - 8 a + a^2]) == 0}
> ```

then [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) each (`/@` is a shortcut for [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html))

```
Solve /@ Thread@Equal[Eigenvalues[{{a, 2} , {3, 4}}], 0]
```

> ```
> {{{a -> 3/2}}, {}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to go is using `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[Min@Abs@Eigenvalues[{{a, 2}, {3, 4}}], a]
(* {3.89083*10^-10, {a -> 1.5}} *)
```

which of course matches the analytic answer [above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105738/9490)